# Replacing values inside a column in a DataFrame PYTHON

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking for better ways to replace values inside a column with respect to certain rules.

My table look like this :

```
data    NB
1Y  1Yf
3Y  3Yf
4Y  4Yf
1M  1Mf
3M  3Mf
1Y  1Yf
3Y  3Yf
5Y  4Yf
```

Here's my code works but im looking for other ways to do it

```py
def test(ls):
    n=0
    while n<len(ls):
        if ls[n]=='1M':
            ls[n]=0.083
            n=n+1
        elif ls[n]=='3M':
            ls[n]=0.25
            n=n+1
        elif ls[n]=='1Y':
            ls[n]=1
            n=n+1
        elif ls[n]=='3Y':
            ls[n]=3
            n=n+1
        elif ls[n]=='4Y':
            ls[n]=4
            n=n+1
        else:
            ls[n]='error'
            n=n+1
test(df['data'])
```

Comment: can you post your table directly here, so it is easier to look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly put a condition on columns and use that to replace values.

```
d = {'1M':0.083,'3M':0.25,'1Y':1,'4Y':4}
for k,d in d.iteritems():
    df['data'][df['data'] == k] = d
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `map`

```
df['data'] = df['data'].map({'1M': 0.083, '3M': 0.25, '1Y':  1, '3Y': 3, '4Y': 4).fillna('error')
```

Using `np.select`

```
df['data'] = np.select([df.data.eq('1M'), df.data.eq('3M'), df.data.eq('1Y'), df.data.eq('3Y'), df.data.eq('4Y')],
                       [0.083, 0.25, 1, 3, 4],
                        default='error')
```

---

A generalized way is to use `timedelta` to annualize your operations for you, taking advantage of vectorization

```
df.data.transform(lambda x: np.timedelta64(x[0], x[1])) /np.timedelta64('1', 'Y') / np.timedelta64('1', 'Y')
```

Demonstration of how it works:

```
>>> np.timedelta64('3', 'M')/np.timedelta64('1', 'Y')
0.25

>>> np.timedelta64('1', 'M')/np.timedelta64('1', 'Y')
0.083333333
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here, one explicit, and one more general.  The first option is using `map` to explicitly define your relationships and then filling `null` values with your `else` clause.

```
>>> d = {'1M': 0.083, '3M': 0.25, '1Y': 1, '3Y': 3, '4Y': 4 }
>>> df['data'].map(d).fillna('error')
0        1
1        3
2        4
3    0.083
4     0.25
5        1
6        3
7    error
Name: data, dtype: object
```

---

However, it seems like you have a fairly well defined rule here.  It seems that if the letter in the first column is a `Y`, you want the number preceding, and if the letter is `M`, you want the number divided by 12.

You can generalize this condition to avoid having to have an explicit dictionary.

---

```
i = df['data'].str.extract(r'(\d+)')[0].astype(int)
j = df['data'].str.endswith('Y')
k = df['data'].str.endswith('M')

conditions = [
    (i < 5) & j,
    (i < 5) & k
]

pd.Series(np.select(conditions, [i, i/12], 'error'))
```

```
0                      1
1                      3
2                      4
3    0.08333333333333333
4                   0.25
5                      1
6                      3
7                  error
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the replace method. We can use nested replace functions. Remember to have inplace = True for making changes inplace.

```py
df.replace(
        to_replace=None,
        value=None,
        inplace=False,
        limit=None,
        regex=False, 
        method='pad',
        axis=None)
```